# why does voltage drop across a resistor

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, power-engineering, electrostatic

I have seen the explanations about the energy lost in from of heat, but that energy comes from the net reduction of kinetic energy of the electrons (reduction of current).  More over voltage is a state function (depends only on the distance) by formula $$V = kQ/r$$
In the analogy of gravity. When we make a ball roll on an inclined plane the difference in potential energy is only depending upon the initial and final height, no matter whether we roll it over a smooth plane (no resistance) or a rough surface (resistance).  The heat released due to friction is compensated by the loss of kinetic energy at the bottom of the inclined plane (the ball going in the smooth plane has more kinetic energy at the bottom due to total conversion of potential energy compared to the one on the rouge surface due to loss in heat).

My question is keeping the above explanations in mind voltage should not drop across a resistor but why does it do so.

Comment: But it's the voltage drop between the two ends of the resistor that makes the current flow through it.

Comment: place a resistor across battery terminals ... where else could the battery voltage drop, if not across the resistor?

Comment: Conduction is inverse parameter to resistance. When current flows the power is dissipated in heat and the energy from time causes temperature to rise according to thermal Rth. Consider  friction like resistance. A change in slope between altitudes like V potential difference may induce a force of current depending on R.

Answer (score 1):

The theoretical model behind Ohm's law (voltage drop beeing proportional to current and resistance) is the [Drude Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drude_model).

One crucial point in this model is, that electrons don't fly or drift unimpeded, but bounce very often against crystal ions (see image; from Wikipedia):

[image]

After each bounce the electrons direction is totally random. The electric field (voltage) has only little time to act on the electrons between bounces to create a net motion (current) in opposite direction of the field.
The result of the model is that current density \$\bf j\$ is proportional to the electric field \$\bf E\$. The proportionality constant \$\sigma\$ is called conductivity (inverse of resistance):

\$\bf{j} = \sigma \bf{E}\$

In [lumped-element-model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumped-element_model) this yields Ohm's law:

\$I = GV\$ or \$ I = \frac{V}{R}\$

Comment: Curd, In the first line of your contribution you write "voltage drop". May I ask "why"?  Isn`t simply the voltage applied to both ends of the part creating inside the E-Field? Is there any "drop"?

Comment: .. because OP asked for the reason of **voltage drop**, i.e. current through resistor is the precondition. If a relationship between physical quantities is a physical law (like Ohm's law resulting from the Drude Model) you can solve it for any quantity if the others are given.

Comment: Of course the current will be caused again by an external E field, but it must satisfy Ohm's law (within the limits where the model is valid)

Comment: Curd, I am aware of the fact that - from the mathematical point of view - any physical law can be solved for any quantity. However, when somebody asks "why does voltage drop..."  I think, he wants a physical explanation of the term "drop". That was the background of my comment - nothing else.

Comment: Then the simple answer is: because the external current source creates a potential difference (=voltage drop) in order to maintain the current; otherwise there wouldn't be any current

Comment: Sorry - but this "simple answer" is wrong. An "external current source" cannot "create a potential difference". During calculation of simple circuits you can do as if this would be the case - however, in reality such a potential difference is always the cause of a corresponding current. Note that each "current source" (lab slang) is a voltage source with a very large source resistance (very often created by using the feedback principle).

Comment: I think now you are contradicting yourself: First you say <<An "external current source" cannot "create a potential difference">>. Then you say <<each "current source" (lab slang) is a voltage source with a very large source resistance (very often created by using the feedback principle).>> Why shouldn't your "voltage source with very large resistance" not be able to create a potential difference (=voltage)???

Comment: My answer: As you can see I have used the term "external current source" as a quote from your comment (therefore the quotation marks). As to your last sentence: Yes, any voltage source (with a small or a large source resistance)  will create a potential difference across one or more connected resistors. However, it is not the current that does this job. Best example: Potentiometer. You can consider it as two resistors in series (one acts as a source resistor and the other part as a load. Question: Is it the current which produces the voltage across the 2nd part or is it the E-field ?

Comment: I think your try to fight a straw man. Of course the voltage is created by the external current source (as I stated). But it is a logical neccessity required by the current. The current is the given precondition and it requires a voltage drop. The current is the cause why voltage is required (by logic and physics) in the given situation.

Comment: Let's try with an analogy: fire is the cause for smoke, not the other way round, but if you see smoke, you know that there is fire. You know there is fire **because** you see smoke and in short sometimes one just says: there is fire because there is smoke (and everybody knows that the smoke is not the physical cause for fire, but the other way round; but smoke is the logical cause why you can know that there is fire). I see and accept that you don't like this usage of "because"; but I consider riding this horse over and over again not helpful in any way and rather tiring.

Comment: Quote; "The current is the given precondition and it requires a voltage drop. " I must admit that I cannot understand this sentence. "Precondition" for what ? If the current "requires a voltage drop" - I think that this voltage drop is a precondition for the current. Again: Current as a precondition for what?

Answer (score 0):

The term "voltage drop" has taken on a new (and somewhat misleading) meaning.

Originally, the term was intended to describe the fact that the voltage avalaible at the battery terminals "drops" when a current is drawn (due to an internal source resistance).

However, today it is very often used as a synonym for "a voltage is created" across a resistor. Such a view "works" and can be used for calculating purposes, but - physically spoken - it is not correct.

The voltage across a resistor is a precondition for the current to flow. No current through the resistor without a driving voltage